# How to dynamically set default date in datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, html, datepicker

I'm using datepicker with the following script:

```
<?php print "$test_date" ?> --> returns 2014,10,25
<script>

$(function() {

$("#mydate").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var dateAsString = dateText;  

    var date = $('#mydate').val();
    var datex = date.replace(/[/]/g,"-"); // 01-01-2013 01:21
    $('#mydatex').val(datex);


  }
})
     .datepicker("setDate",new Date());

     //.datepicker("setDate","<?php echo $test_date; ?>";  --> this doen't work 
     // returns blank date
});
</script>
```

the default date is set to the current date.  Is there a way to dynamically set the default date with a variable passed into my form from php?  i.e When I render the form I pass into it $test_date  which = "2014,12,25"

and here's the top of the form:

```
<form name="myForm" action="createevent.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="get"> 
<h1 style="color:blue;">Skipper Input Page</h1>
<div class="skipperinput"">

<input type="text" id="mydate" name="mydate" value= ""/><br>
<label>Date</label>
<input type="hidden" id="mydatex" name="mydatex"/>
```

Comment: You should set the `dateFormat` option instead of _fixing_ the date by regex.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.  what the heck is regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 .datepicker("setDate", new Date("<?php echo $new_default_date; ?>"));
```

Comment: Can you give more information other than just "no it doesn't work"?  Are you posting with a form field named _new_default_date_? What kind of error message(s) are you getting?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help!  If I add:  
   <?php print "$new_default_date"; ?>  at the top of my form it prints out the date.  there's nothing in $_POST or $_GET.  I get a blank for the default date.  The setDate is inside a function so I don't think the php echo works.  Here's the top of my form:<form name="myForm" action="createevent.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="get"> 
<h1 style="color:blue;">Skipper Input Page</h1>

<br><br>
<div class="skipperinput"">
   
   <input type="text" id="mydate" name="mydate" value= ""/><br>
   <label>Date</label><br/><br>

Comment: Then just replace  _$_POST["new_default_date"]_ with _$new_default_date_. I've edited the answer.

Comment: no that doesn't work. you can't do php echo inside the function.  I've edited the original question to make it a little clearer

Comment: Don't see why you can't.  Please look at my revised answer and try that :)

Comment: just needed to remove the quotes, thanks for your help